# How to optimize a variable with dynamic shape?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Based on following code, m0 is a constant with shape (3,1) but got changed its shape inside the while loop.
So after the while loop, the Tensorflow doesn't know its shape, but I use set_shape to change it to correct shape.
However, when you run it through optimization(take gradients), it pop a error:

```python
Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.  Forward operation: while_29/Enter_1.  Input index: 0. Original input shape: (3, 1).  Calculated input gradient shape: (15, 1)
```

It seems like the gradients still treat the shape as (3,1) but our set_shape change it to shape (15,1). Could anyone please tell me how to fix?

```python
sess = tf.Session()

i0 = tf.constant(0)
m0 = tf.ones([3, 1])
x = tf.get_variable('www', shape=(3,1), initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
loop = 5
def _cond(i0, m0):
  return tf.less(i0, loop-1)

def _res(i0, m0):
  n = tf.ones([3, 1]) + x
  m0 = tf.concat([m0, n], axis=0)
  return i0+1, m0

i0, m0 = tf.while_loop(
    _cond, _res, loop_vars=[i0, m0],
    shape_invariants=[i0.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, 1])])

m0.set_shape([loop*3,1])
opt = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1)

grad = opt.compute_gradients(m0)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(grad))
```

Comment: The optimizer is irrelevant here. But a MWE replacing that "compute gradients" call with tf.gradients still throws the error. In any case, it would be clearer to remove the optimizer from your question to help isolate the issue

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your problem can be efficiently solved by creating `m0` like this:

```
m0 = 1 + tf.tile( x, (loop,1) )
```

However, the answer to the underlying problem you have above is that you are growing `m0` in a loop. However, you know the size that you want `m0` to take, so if you really must use a `while_loop`, then you should use a TensorArray. Something like this:

```
def mystack(x, n):
    loop_vars = [
        tf.constant(0, tf.int32),
        tf.TensorArray(x.dtype, size=n),
    ]
    _, fx = tf.while_loop(
        lambda j, _: j < n,
        lambda j, result: (j + 1, result.write(j, 1+x)),
        loop_vars
    )
    return tf.reshape( fx.stack(), (-1,1) )

x = tf.constant( numpy.random.randn(3,1), tf.float32 )
loop = 5
m = mystack(x,loop)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(m).shape)
```